# The notion of a curve in the context of line integrals

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, integration, vector-analysis

For brevity I'm making the following assumption: I'm only talking
about regular curves on $\left[a,b\right]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,
and line integrals of scalar fields.

[Since there are a lot of questions at the end and you have to dig through the text below to make sense of them, I'm willing to offer **150 bounty points** for a *complete and thorough* answer by a *knowledgeable person in either differential geometry or vector analysis (or related fields)* of *all the questions*.

There are three common ways to define curves:

1. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) they are defined as *mappings* $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
2. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) a curve is used as a *subset* $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that's the image
   of a (regular) $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$- which clearly doesn't work with the concept from 1. (although Wikipedia
   has linked to that - has no one spotted this so far ?)
3. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Reparametrization_and_equivalence_relation) curves are *equivalence classes* of mappings $\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$
   (which are equivalent if they are obtained from reparametrisations
   of eachother).

Now these definitions relate in different ways to the concept of a
line integral over scalar field $f$ along $\gamma$.

If I take 1. as my definition, I can define 
$$
\int_{\gamma}fd s:=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\left\Vert \dot{\gamma\left(t\right)}\right\Vert d t
$$
without mathematical problems, but I have the "psychological"
problem that I would like my line integral to not be dependent on
all the information $\gamma$ contains (since, for example, different
reparametrisations of $\gamma$ give me the same $\int_{\gamma}f$)
- of course I can show that this holds in a separate theorem, but
this just seems ugly).

If I take 2. as my definition, I can define 
$$
\int_{C}fds:=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\left\Vert \dot{\gamma\left(t\right)}\right\Vert d t
$$
where $\gamma$ is any parametrisation $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$
that has image $C$. This has mathematical problems: There are (regular)
curves that have the same image , but aren't equivalent, so have different
lengths. For example 
$$
t\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos t\\
\sin t
\end{array}\right)\ \text{and}\ t\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos2t\\
\sin2t
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $t\in\left[0,2\pi\right]$. So $\int_{C}f s$ isn't well
defined since it depends on the choice of the parametrisation of $C$.
But from a "psychological" perspective I like this the most,
since it only has a geometric content (since $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n})$
and not a dynamic one (I don't know anything about the "speed"
with which $C$ is traced) and my personal view is, that line integral
(or arc lengths, since I could have discussed this issue in the same
matter with arc lengths instead of line integrals) should be purely
geometrical.

If I take 3. as my definition, I can define 
$$
\int_{\hat{\gamma}}fd s:=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\left\Vert \dot{\gamma\left(t\right)}\right\Vert d t
$$
where $\hat{\gamma}$ is the equivalance class of $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
This seems to me to be a compromise between 1. and 2.: The line integral
is (from the start) independent of reparametrisations - but it isn't
purely geometric, as the definitions from 2.
But other weird issues arise in this case: Since a curve is a set of mappings (which makes up the equivalence class) I loose a comfortable way of speaking about curves by the following subtle point: I can't say anymore that a smooth curve is also a continuous curve, since for example the equivalence class of the identity on $[0,1]$ (taken as a curve in $\mathbb{R}$), viewed as a smooth curve (i.e. as the set $\{f\mid f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ is smooth and can be reparametrised to be the identity}\}$) does *not* contain $$t\mapsto\begin{cases}
2t, & 0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
1, & \frac{1}{2}<t\leq1
\end{cases}$$which *is* is in the equivalence class of the identity, viewed as a continuous curve (i.e. as the set $\{f\mid f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ is continuous and can be reparametrised to be the identity}\}$) .

**Questions:**

A. Is there a standart definition of what a curve (and thus a line
integral) is ? If there isn't a definition that's valid for the whole
of mathematics, is the definition at least separately standarised
in subfields (like differential geometric, vector analysis etc.) ?

B. Is my view that line integrals and arc lengths should only depend
on a purely geometric object of a curve "correct" ? (You may
understand what you wish by "correct".)

C. Could I perhaps save the definition of $\int_{C}f ds$ from 2.,
by modifying its definition so that it says 
$$
\int_{C}fds:=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\left\Vert \dot{\gamma\left(t\right)}\right\Vert d t
$$only for those $\gamma$ that are *injective* on $\left(a,b\right)$ ? (In this case I would need a proposition, that for *every* $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists an *injective* $\gamma':\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ have the same image. Does such a proposition exist ?)

Would I exclude important physical phenomena by this alternative definition of 2.?

D. I've know that there also a fourth definition if a curve, namely
as a topological space locally homeomorphic to a line. How does this
definition reduce to each of the three definitions above (as Wikipedia
says at the beginning of the article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve
about curves) and how do I define a line integral (or arc length)
by this definition ?

Note: I've already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92741/properly-defining-a-smooth-curve) in case you wanted to direct me there.

Comment: Since I haven't got as much as a single comment in two days I'm starting to be vary of offering a bounty beforehand, since there may be no one who might claim it; and 100 isn't a fluke (for me...actually it was 150 at the beginning, because the question was urgent then, but now it's not so urgent anymore and since no one answered I lowered it to 100.). So I'm thinking, a better idea is to wait and award the bounty afterwards - in this case I'm not going to loose it, if no one answers. (Don't worry, you *will* get your bounty.) So, is there really no one who could answer this question ?

Comment: Very interesting and good question. One must add to all of this, the interpretation as integrating a 1-form over a 1-dim manifold. We sweep so much of these under the rug in the usual calculus courses.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice question IMHO, and my take is as follows (not a full answer maybe and not bounty worth btw):

- The image definition is certainly ill-posed, as your example illustrates. Possible fix: $\forall p\in C$, define $t_p = \min\{t: \gamma(t) = p\}$, and redefine $\gamma = \gamma|_{D}$ where $D =  \cup_{p\in C}t_{p}$. BTW Wikipedia says the following in the entry of Curve:

  > The distinction between a curve and its image is important. Two distinct curves may have the same image. For example, a line segment can be traced out at different speeds, or a circle can be traversed a different number of times. Many times, however, we are just interested in the image of the curve. It is important to pay attention to context and convention in reading.
  >   Terminology is also not uniform. Often, topologists use the term "path" for what we are calling a curve, and "curve" for what we are calling the image of a curve. The term "curve" is more common in vector calculus and differential geometry.
- Mathematically, I prefer to define in the first way, i.e., as a mapping to avoid ambiguity so that different parametrizations lead to the same value for the line integral. A definition restricting an oriented curve to have a designated parameterisation is good for me too. "Psychologically", I prefer the physical way, i.e., view $f = F\cdot \gamma'/\|\gamma'\|$, provided there exists such field $F$. Then the scalar integral is the same as the work done by the field $F$ when a unit mass point particle traverses the whole curve $\gamma$ from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$. In your first example, if using the second parametrization, the particle rotates the circle twice, and we have twice the work done.
- I agree with you on that "the line integrals and arc lengths should only depend on a purely geometric object of a curve", so it is "subjectively correct" for myself :) The reason I prefer the physical way, is that, we can then associate the line integral with the bilinear dual pair between forms and chains. Bilinearity is in that
  $$
  \langle \gamma, a_1 \omega_1 + a_2\omega_2\rangle = \int_{\gamma} (a_1 \omega_1 + a_2\omega_2) = a_1 \int_{\gamma}\omega_1 + a_2\int_{\gamma}\omega_2,
  $$
  and 
  $$
  \langle c_1\gamma_1 + c_2 \gamma_2, \omega\rangle = \int_{c_1\gamma_1 + c_2 \gamma_2} \omega = c_1 \int_{\gamma_1}\omega + c_2\int_{\gamma_2}\omega.
  $$
  The linearity in $\gamma$ essentially rules out the ambiguity in definition 2. For in this view, the "curve" is viewed as an element in the 1-chain vector space, which includes the piecewise smooth curves being continuous not smooth. By your example in the third definition, reparametrization seems working fine "psychologically" on for curves such that $\gamma'(t)$ not vanishing for all $t$, for now smooth curves are continuous curves when the equivalence restricts on $\gamma$ of which $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$.